# Tool to visualy organize data and information

Tags: windows, gratis, information-management

I'm looking for a software that would help me organize huge amounts of information in a visual form. I want to store notes like in the journal, I want to store links, thoughts, ideas, pictures in the form of a tree, something like a mind map. I need a tool to help me remember and analyze data.

For those familiar with Harry Potter it would be something like a Pensieve tool used by Dumbledore. For those more familiar with IT it should be something like Maltego, Casefile, Pearltrees or XMind, but dedicated for *huge* information overload.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean something like https://keynote.en.softonic.com/ ? There are plenty of similar questions on this site - did you look at them? This is rather road, so without more detail, you might not get the best possible answer. Also, which operating system (hint: add the [tag:windows] tag)? And do you have a budget, or don't you want to pay (hint: add the [tag:gratis] tag)

Comment: Also I suggest to add more tags

Comment: I've tried KeyNote NF - it look promising, but something more visual would be better. KeyNote is pretty much like an ole Windows 95 style program. I've also included some more tagging in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [iMapping Tool](http://www.imapping.info/) could be right for you. It is a visual knowledge mapping tool that lets you organize your text snippets, files and pictures visually on what could be described as an infinite pinboard. Items can be nested and interlinked so you can add structure as your collection grows.

While Mind Maps add branches from the inside out and they are very nice for smaller topics that fit on one page (roughly 50-100 items), in iMaps the hierarchy goes from thie outside in, which makes it suitable for large collections of items (up to 10.000 and more).

The website is in German, while the tool itself is English. Just check out the video - you will get an impression.

Disclaimer: The iMapping tool is my own development I sell it commercially.There is also a free version availabe though.

Comment: As far as I can see this one is most complete for my requirements.

Comment: @KrzysztofJakóbczyk Then it would be cool if you would upvote this answer and mak it as the correct one. ;)

Comment: It's done :) ! I really thought that my rep points won't allow me to upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

You may not get reposnses for many tools, but you can do some investigating on your own:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concept-_and_mind-mapping_software

In the Note-taking link, there is a column that describes the organizing prinicple, one of which is *tree*.

I have used *Tinderbox*, *Evernote*, *TheBrain* among the proprietary tools. If you can identify a few that you like, you may be able to find articles that compare the two, for example:
https://www.slant.co/versus/2121/2152/~evernote_vs_the-brain

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution can be [Mindomo](https://www.mindomo.com/), there are several points that make it my preferred sw in their class:

- There are free version ([between others](https://www.mindomo.com/pricing.htm))
- It's available on ALL platforms: Win, MacOS, Linux, iOS, Android
- Stand-alone sw: You can work offline locally and upload them online for easy sharing (admits online and mobile synchronization)
- Upload Video, audio, attachments
- Office365 integration

It's higly oriented to scholar environments, but also can be used in differents way, like [Project Management](https://www.mindomo.com/tasks.htm), for example, with very interesting features. Also there are [other visions](https://www.mindomo.com/mind-maps) that can be applied to use this product.

[image: Mental maps]

Comment: This one is interesting, but very similar to mind mapping software I've been using recently. For simple maps it will be just fine, but for multi-disciplinary information organization I find mind maps to be too limited.

Comment: Then can you explain more clearly in your question what you are looking for? Because 2 of 3 answers think that Mind Mapping will solve your problem. Please expand your question to say why not (you even say "something like a mind map"). Thanks